# Alternate of the parallel flash

Tags: non-volatile-memory, addressing, flash-memories

Hi I am looking for an alternate of the flash [S29AL016J70BFI010](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cypress-semiconductor-corp/S29AL016J70BFI010/3761555), its a top boot sector device.
unfortunately I have not found any 16Mb flash with top boot sectors.
Although I am able to find 32Mb or 64Mb flash with same specifications, but they have extra address pins which is NC in the design. [S29JL032J70BHI320](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cypress-semiconductor-corp/S29JL032J70BHI320/5788075)

I just want to know, can I use higher flash memory as 16Mb, if I keep the higher address pins A20-A21 NC? or is still require to connect to MCU/GND/VCC?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have unused address pin on flash, but you have to take into account, that it obviously limits the amount of things you can address, for instance in the [Datasheet of S29JL032J70BHI320](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-S29JL032J_32_Mb_(4M_X_8_BIT_2M_X_16_BIT)_3_V_SIMULTANEOUS_READ_WRITE_FLASH-AdditionalTechnicalInformation-v11_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ed71e7d5831&utm_source=cypress&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2021) on page 16 you can see

[image]

And page 18

[image]

You can see what sectors will be inaccessible to you. Make sure everything you want to store will fit into where it is supposed to fit. There are also protected sectors, if you need those, you can have same problem, if you use them.

Next, before you discard some address pin, it's a good idea to check if any address pin has some special function, such as

[image]

Just make sure you don't throw away some pin, which has some special function/purpose you might later need. Not all address pins are equal. I didn't find A20 to have any special function.

I looked through the electrical characteristics too (quickly), but didn't find any integrated pull-up or pull-down on the address pins, and floating pin doesn't seem to be a good idea, since you would probably prefer to address the same sector with the same A12-A19.

I checked the package pinouts, both BGA and SMD have neither Vcc nor GND in close proximity to A20 for you to fix A20 to a certain level. You may want to find some solution to fix A20 level, if everything else suits you.